# Alarm BroadcastReceiver doesn't work on real devices

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have an alarm in my Android app that work in AVD correct. But it doesn't work in real devices.
What's wrong here?
And that's my BroadcastReceiver:

```
package com.junglesofts.maraudersmap;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
{    
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
     {   
         PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
         wl.acquire();

         // Put here YOUR code.
         Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm!!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

         wl.release();
     }

 public void SetAlarm(Context context)
 {
     AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
     PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 10 * 1, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
 }

 public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
 {
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
     PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     alarmManager.cancel(sender);
 }
}
```

I comment my Androidmanifest too.

Comment: The first thing i noticed is wrong is your question. Where is your code? We are NOT wizards

Comment: That's my Manifest:
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="projectX.spammessagesblocker.Alarm"></receiver>

Comment: Thank you  Blaze Tama. I added some more information.